# remove numbers after the string and () along with what is inside

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when removing numbers and parenthesis along with what is inside in Python. It is suggested to use str.replace. However, the challenge here is that the numbers are not certain numbers. I only know I need to remove whatever the number is, but I am not sure what it may be. For parenthesis, I only know I need remove () along with what is inside. However, the content inside also varies. For instance, If I have the following data set:

```
    import pandas as pd
    a = pd.Series({'Country':'China 1', 'Capital': 'Bei Jing'})
    b = pd.Series({'Country': 'United States (of American)', 'Capital': 'Washington'})
    c = pd.Series({'Country': 'United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)', 'Capital': 'London'})
    d = pd.Series({'Country': 'France 2', 'Capital': 'Paris'})
    e = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c,d])
```

Now in Column 'Country', the values are 'China 1', 'United States (of American)', 'United Kingdom (of...)' and 'France 2'. After replacement/remove, I want to get rid of all numbers and parenthesis along with content inside, and want the values in Column Country to be 'China', 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'France'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` here with `regex`.

```
series1.str.replace("^([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*).*", r"\1")
```

See demo.You can replace with your own series and other modifications.

https://regex101.com/r/lIScpi/2

You can also directly modify frame.

```
a = pd.Series({'Country': 'China 1', 'Capital': 'Bei Jing'})
b = pd.Series({'Country': 'United States (of American)', 'Capital': 'Washington'})
c = pd.Series({'Country': 'United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern Ireland)', 'Capital': 'London'})
d = pd.Series({'Country': 'France 2', 'Capital': 'Paris'})
e = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c, d])
print e
e['Country'] = e['Country'].str.replace("^([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*).*", r"\1")
print e
```

Output before `replace`.

```
  Capital                                            Country
0    Bei Jing                                            China 1
1  Washington                        United States (of American)
2      London  United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern ...
3       Paris                                           France 2
```

Output after `replace`

```
  Capital         Country
0    Bei Jing           China
1  Washington   United States
2      London  United Kingdom
3       Paris          France
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. It solved my problem perfectly. I am new to regex. Besides the demo, I appreciate a lot if you can also recommend some tutorial or reading material.